# Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number optimistic concurrency exceptions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an action method, in which it throws the following error.

```
dbcontext.TBL_ADMIN_GROUP_ROLE.Attach(objgrouprole);

var entry = dbcontext.Entry(objgrouprole);
entry.Property(x => x.IsDeleted).IsModified = true;

objgrouprole.IsDeleted = 1;

dbcontext.Entry(objgrouprole).State = EntityState.Modified;
dbcontext.SaveChanges();

return RedirectToAction("ManageGroupRole");
```

Comment: your entry has the name entry, why are you doing some operations on objgrouprole?

Comment: infact i want to update some of database table column..... i want to update just isdeleted=0